# Get line matching a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string in a file called mib.txt:

```
[name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=myrouter.ad.local (OCTET STRING)]
```

name the following code:

```
f = File.read("/temp/mib.txt")
name = f.match(/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0/)
puts "device name is #{name}"
```

It returns the `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0` just like I asked it to, but what I really want is to find the string the contains `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0` and parse out the value myrouter.

Comment: In future, please make code look like code by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must extend your regex to catch the value inside a regex group.

```
s = File.read("/temp/mib.txt")
m = s.match /\[name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=([\S]+) \(OCTET STRING\)/
puts "device name is #{m[1]}"
```

Comment: Your example is good, but I only want the my-router. yours gives me my-router.ad.local. I tried to modify m = s.match /\\[name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=([\S]+) \\(OCTET STRING\\)/
 to m = s.match /\\[name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=([\S]+) \.ad.local/ but that doesn't work

Comment: You can do with regex also, but I would suggest you to filter the hostname from domain using a second line of code. Just use the example bellow.

name = m[1].split('.')[0]

Comment: yeah, I did the split and it worked, but I was hoping to find the regex way. Thanks for all your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You always could use `scan`:

```
>> name = f.scan(/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=(\w+)/).flatten.to_s
=> "myrouter"
```

If you want the `ad.local` part as well, then instead do:

```
>> name = f.scan(/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=([\w\.]+)/).flatten.to_s
=> "myrouter.ad.local"
```

Comment: if the string looks like this [name=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0, value=my-router.ad.local (OCTET STRING) it won't get my-router. I'm sure that its because the regex needs to change to include more than ([\w\.]+)/) could you tell me what I would need to add to get everything between the "value=" and the .ad.local.  Thanks